# LineItem adjustment doesn't affect Order total price Spree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, spree

I'm building an app using Spree 3.6.6 where i need to make Line item adjustment, i'm using the below code

```
line_item = Spree::LineItem.find(id)
line_item.adjustments.create!(
  amount: 6,
  order: line_item.order,
  label: 'Test',
  adjustable: line_item
)
```

however the line item adjustment is being created successfully, but the total price of the order doesn't change, what may be the error ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can force your order to update totals with `order.update_with_updater!`